# How to display an image's matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can we display an image's matrix in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

I have read the image using [imread](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) and have converted it into binary image. How do I see an image's matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see the actual matrix, use `disp(I)` where `I` is the image. If you want to view it as an image, use `imagesc(I)` or `imshow(I)`.

Comment: It is important to mention that you need the Image Processing Toolbox to use `imshow(I)`.